# Allow add to cart 3 products max for a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am trying to send out a maximum of 3 free samples to customers with free shipping.

I have created some 0 priced product and set them in "samples" product category.

This specific products have option "sold individually" so customers can only have one of each sample.

I cannot figure out how to allow only a maximum of 3 samples products from this product category on cart.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done easily using `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` action hook to limit customers to a maximum of 3 items from "sample" product category, this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'max_3_items_for_samples', 20, 3 );
function max_3_items_for_samples( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    // HERE define your product category ID, slug or name.
    $category = 'clothing';
    $limit = 3; // HERE set your limit
    $count = 0;

    // Loop through cart items checking for specific product categories
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cat_item ) {
        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cat_item['product_id'] ) )
            $count++;
    }
    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && $count == $limit )
        $count++;

    // Total item count for the defined product category is more than 3
    if( $count > $limit ){
        // HERE set the text for the custom notice
        $notice = __('Sorry, you can not add to cart more than 3 free samples.', 'woocommerce');
        // Display a custom notice
        wc_add_notice( $notice, 'error' );
        // Avoid adding to cart
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: I am also looking for something similar solution for full store allows only one quantity to add to basket, but if the category is "Games" allow multiple quantity.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution does not work.  1) It allows you to initially add more than the limit the first time the product is added.  I believe this is because the validation comes before the items are added to the cart, yet the function above loops through items that are already in the cart and 2) it lets the user enter as many of a product that they want, on the the /cart/ page because the woocommerce_update_cart_validation filter is not used.