# Restrict cart additions of ‘product_cat’ when more than 5 ’product_cat’ in cart already (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shopping-cart

ORIGINAL, SEMI-WORKING CODE:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );
function only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $total_count = $cart_count + $quantity;

 if ( has_term( ‘category’, 'product_cat’, $product_id ) && ( $cart_count >= 5 || $total_count > 5 ) ) {
        $passed = false; // Set to false
        $notice = __( "Only 5 category additions allowed per day.", "woocommerce" ); // Notice to display
  }
    if( ! $passed )
        wc_add_notice( $notice, 'error' );

    return $passed;
}
```

Problem with the above code is I can’t add any more ‘product_cat’ items to cart when the OVERALL cart total is 5 or more. It should only restrict me when the cart total of items from a SPECIFIC CATEGORY is 5 or more.

How do I make it so that essentially ‘$cart_count’ is only equal to the number of cart items **from a specific ‘product_cat’?**

I have tried the following, adding a new $count variable, counting each cart item from a specific category.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );
function only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $total_count = $cart_count + $quantity;

        $count = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( has_term( $term, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
            $count += $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    // Returning category count
    return $count;

 if ( has_term( ‘category’, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && ( $count >= 5 || $total_count > 5 ) ) {
        $passed = false; // Set to false
        $notice = __( "Only 5 category additions allowed per day.", "woocommerce" ); // Notice to display
  }
    if( ! $passed )
        wc_add_notice( $notice, 'error' );

    return $passed;
}
```

I thought that replacing the ‘ $cart_count >= 5 ‘ with the new variable ‘ $count >= 5 ‘ would change the ‘if’ statement to only work when the cart items from a specific category are += 5.

However, this isn’t what happens and the code does not work at all now. I can add infinite products to cart.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: you return the function back where it came from too early. remove the 'return $count' line

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for? [Allow add to cart 3 products max for a specific product category in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015289/allow-add-to-cart-3-products-max-for-a-specific-product-category-in-woocommerce/49015436#49015436)

Comment: @ 7uc1f3r This worked for me.